# Multiple else to detect if a drive exists

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I made a small batch file to copy the contents of a drive to external storage, but obviously, there is many different letters that can be assigned to an external disc/drive.

Basically I want to do something similar to

```
if exist E: (
set "destination=E:"
) else ( 
set "destination=F:"
) else ( 
set "destination=G:"
```

Another thing I would like to know is how can you check if the storage is over a certain amount or under a certain amount?  I ask this because the usual letters are C and D for Windows partitions, or C and D for partition and a CD/DVD reader.

Obviously a CD/DVD reader has no storage, so if it would be greater than the storage specified it would got to the next else and keep going setting %destination% to the next letter.  I have thought of checking to see if it's USB or CD/DVD, as you can make E, F, G partitions on your internal drive, but I  have no clue how.

Here is what the original file looks like, just in case you want to know what I am doing:

```
@echo off
title Backup

REM Here is where I will place the code to check for drives
set "srcd=E:\"

REM Here is my destination, the computers partition for C.
set "destd=C:"

REM It will then be set to this, dir is where I make logs etc, dir2 is where I will copy the files to, log is obviously, a text file.

set "dir=%destd%\BackupUSB"
set "dir2=%destd%\%dir%\Files"
set "log=%dir%\Log.txt"


REM I am now finding if the destination exists as it will be copied to a folder, if it does not exist I will make it..

if exist "%dir2%" (
cd "%dir%"
) else (
md "%dir2%"
)

REM I am now going to create the log file saying the date and time the transfer took place.


for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('date /t') do (
set d=%%a
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('time /t') do (
set t=%%a
)

REM Add date and time to show on same line.
set "dt=%d%%t%"

REM I now write the text to the file.
echo ==================>>"%log%"
echo =%dt%=>>"%log%"
echo ==================>>"%log%"

REM if the source exists copy the files, if not then save a message to a text file saying it failed.

if exist "%srcd%" (
cd %srcd%
REM /Q copies silently.

echo please wait while your files are copied from %srcd% to %dir2%
xcopy "%srcd%" /E /I /Q /H "%dir2%" /y
echo Copied "%srcd%" to "%dir2%" [%dt%]>>"%log%"
) else (
echo Failed to copy files from drive %srcd% to "%dir2%" please check the drive/path exists and run the batch file again [%dt%]>>"%log%"
)
```

Comment: Which `else` weights more?? more than one `else` does not make any sense at all; how should execution decide which `else` to execute?? However, you can nest another complete `if`/`else` clause into the first `else`... Anyway, you could use a `wmic` query to list available and suitable drives: `wmic LogicalDisk where DriveType=3 get DeviceID`...

Comment: Any reason why you want to copy to the first available device rather than just run the batch file with the drive specified as a parameter - it seems less risky than letting your batch file make a choice for you.

Comment: Meant for ease of use, so you can just click, really for my own benefit copying a lot of files at college without prompting and pausing, this way I can leave it to run and copy away while I do work.  Would be nice if there was a way for it to do set "drive=" and wait for me to tell it what to set...  Would anyone know how to do this?  And thank, I was aware you can nest ifs but wasn't sure of else, although I don't know how I would make it so the output would be set to "drive"